# assign meaningful names to buffers in helm-mini?

Tags: org-mode, helm

`org-attach` creates a directory for an entry in the entry.

In `helm-mini` this directory shows as a long sequence of numbers and letters, thus meaningless and impossible to quickly identify different directories.

Is it possible to assign some useful name in `helm-mini` so that when I launch it I can quickly know which directory is which?

Comment: Screenshot?  This does not sound like the normal behavior.